# Cumulative distribution proof

Tags: probability

I have to prove $$P[x_1 < X \le x_2,y_1 < Y \le y_2] = P[x_1 < X \le x_2]P[y_1 < Y \le y_2]$$ using the property $F(x,y)=F(x)F(y)$, which is the cumulative distribution function, where $X$ and $Y$ are independent. I know to prove this I need to start from the definition of a cumulative distribution function. I did $$F(x_2,y_2)-F(x_1,y_2)-F(x_2,y_1)+F(x_1,y_1)$$ so far. I don't know where to go from here. What do i do next and how do i solve the problem?

Comment: @JimmyR. Yes im sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the independence ($F_{X,Y}(x,y)=F_X(x)F_Y(y)$)  in order to arrive at:
$$\cdots =F_{X}\left(x_{2}\right)F_{Y}\left(y_{2}\right)-F_{X}\left(x_{2}\right)F_{Y}\left(y_{1}\right)-F_{X}\left(x_{1}\right)F_{Y}\left(y_{2}\right)+F_{X}\left(x_{1}\right)F_{Y}\left(y_{1}\right)=\left[F_{X}\left(x_{2}\right)-F_{X}\left(x_{1}\right)\right]\left[F_{Y}\left(y_{2}\right)-F_{Y}\left(y_{1}\right)\right]=P\left(x_{1}<X\leq x_{2}\right)P\left(y_{1}<Y\leq y_{2}\right)$$